# Changing the default delimiter in summarise_all in R dply package

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm combining my duplicated values into a single column using delimiters. I'm using the R dplyr library.

```
library (dplyr)
Input = read.csv("test.csv")
test=Input%>%
group_by(V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6)%>%
summarise_all(~toString(na.omit(.)))
```

**My input data looks like this.***

| V1 | V2 | V3 | V4 | V5 | V6 | V7 | V8 | V9 | V10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chr1 | 12364 | 12365 | A | T | Lung | 1236 | cosmic | Cancer, dominant | reported |
| chr1 | 12364 | 12365 | A | T | Lung | 3531 | Pubed | recessive |  |
| chr1 | 12364 | 12365 | A | T | heart | 4616 | HGMD | dominant | pathogenic |
| chr1 | 12364 | 12365 | A | T | brain | 9471 | Pubed | recessive |  |
| chr1 | 12364 | 12365 | A | T | Lung |  | cosmic | Cancer |  |
| chr1 | 12364 | 12365 | A | T | heart | 36481 | Pubed | Cancer | benign |
| chr1 | 12364 | 12365 | A | T | Lung | 8351 | cosmic | Cancer |  |
| chr3 | 19261 | 19262 | G | C | Lung | 453 | HGMD | Cancer | likely pathogenic |
| chr5 | 171672 | 171673 | T | G |  | 6451 | HGMD | Cancer | likely pathogenic |
| chr15 | 10391 | 10391 | G | T |  | 8537 | HGMD | Cancer | likely pathogenic |

**My output looks like this.**

| V1 | V2 | V3 | V4 | V5 | V6 | V7 | V8 | V9 | V10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chr1 | 12364 | 12365 | A | T | brain | 9471 | Pubed | recessive |  |
| chr1 | 12364 | 12365 | A | T | heart | 4616, 36481 | HGMD, Pubed | dominant, Cancer | pathogenic, benign |
| chr1 | 12364 | 12365 | A | T | Lung | 1236, 3531, 8351 | cosmic, Pubed, cosmic, cosmic | Cancer, dominant, recessive, Cancer, Cancer | reported, , , |
| chr15 | 10391 | 10391 | G | T |  | 8537 | HGMD | Cancer | likely pathogenic |
| chr3 | 19261 | 19262 | G | C | Lung | 453 | HGMD | Cancer | likely pathogenic |
| chr5 | 171672 | 171673 | T | G |  | 6451 | HGMD | Cancer | likely |

The problem is that my data already has a comma as the delimiter. So, I need to change the delimiter from the default comma to something else. Can anyone suggest me any better ideas for it?

Comment: Hi @Mano: please consider to improve your question. Including some data would be useful. You can use `dput()` on your data (`dput(head(data))`) or build a reproducible example using fake data or data available in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `summarise_all(~paste(., collapse = "|"))` instead.

Example:

```
library(tidyverse)

n <- 30
db <- tibble(x = sample(letters[1:4], n, replace = T),
             y = sample(letters[1:5], n, replace = T))
db %>% group_by(x) %>% summarise_all(~paste(., collapse = "|")) %>% ungroup()
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  x     y                  
  <chr> <chr>              
1 a     b|a|c|d|d|e|a|b|b|a
2 b     c|b|e|c|b|c|b|a    
3 c     a|a|d|b|d|e|b|d|e|a
4 d     a|d
```

However, I don't quite understand the problem with the comma in your input dataset: once it has been imported, it's no longer a comma-separated file. Of course, if you want to write the result as csv, you may change the separator, but you could also use quotes around field values.